# okhttp client throwing connection leak warning

Tags: java, okhttp, connection-leaks

I see that the connection leak warning is thrown when `response.body()` isn't closed.

Below is the code snippet that is throwing the warning.

```
Request request = (new okhttp3.Request.Builder()).get().url(httpUrlBuilder.build()).addHeader("Origin", this.requestUrl.getProtocol() + "://" + this.requestUrl.getHost() + ":" + this.requestUrl.getPort()).build();
    this.webSocket = this.clonedClient.newWebSocket(request, new WebSocketListener() {
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            if(response != null && response.body() != null) {
                response.body().close();
            }

            WatchConnectionManager.logger.debug("WebSocket successfully opened");
            WatchConnectionManager.this.webSocketRef.set(webSocket);
            WatchConnectionManager.this.currentReconnectAttempt.set(0);
            WatchConnectionManager.this.started.set(true);
            WatchConnectionManager.this.queue.clear();
            WatchConnectionManager.this.queue.add(Boolean.valueOf(true));
        }

        public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
            if(WatchConnectionManager.this.forceClosed.get()) {
                WatchConnectionManager.logger.debug("Ignoring onFailure for already closed/closing websocket", t);
                if(response != null && response.body() != null) {
                    response.body().close();
                }

            } else if(response != null && response.code() == 200) {
                WatchConnectionManager.this.queue.add(new KubernetesClientException("Received 200 on websocket", response.code(), (Status)null));
                response.body().close();
            } else {
                if(response != null) {
                    Status status = OperationSupport.createStatus(response);
                    if(response.body() != null) {
                        response.body().close();
                    }

                    WatchConnectionManager.logger.warn("Exec Failure: HTTP {}, Status: {} - {}", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(response.code()), status.getCode(), status.getMessage(), t});
                    if(!WatchConnectionManager.this.started.get()) {
                        WatchConnectionManager.this.queue.clear();
                        WatchConnectionManager.this.queue.add(new KubernetesClientException(status));
                    }
                } else {
                    WatchConnectionManager.logger.warn("Exec Failure", t);
                    if(!WatchConnectionManager.this.started.get()) {
                        WatchConnectionManager.this.queue.clear();
                        WatchConnectionManager.this.queue.add(new KubernetesClientException("Failed to start websocket", t));
                    }
                }

                if(WatchConnectionManager.this.currentReconnectAttempt.get() >= WatchConnectionManager.this.reconnectLimit && WatchConnectionManager.this.reconnectLimit >= 0) {
                    WatchConnectionManager.this.closeEvent(new KubernetesClientException("Connection failure", t));
                } else {
                    WatchConnectionManager.this.scheduleReconnect();
                }
            }
        }
```

Can someone point out where the error could be and any potential bug in the code?

The error log after setting the log level to FINE is as follows:

```
Feb 16, 2018 12:27:55 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
WARNING: A connection to https://192.168.42.69:8443/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
java.lang.Throwable: response.body().close()
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.getStackTraceForCloseable(Platform.java:143)
at okhttp3.RealCall.captureCallStackTrace(RealCall.java:78)
at okhttp3.RealCall.enqueue(RealCall.java:87)
at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.connect(RealWebSocket.java:180)
at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newWebSocket(OkHttpClient.java:427)
```

Comment: I don't see any branches where response body wouldn't be closed, which would mean that this snipped should not throw any warnings. If I'm not right, can you highlight the problem code somehow?

Comment: Not sure where the problem is. But setting the log level to FINE points to `this.webSocket = this.clonedClient.newWebSocket(request, new WebSocketListener() {` above.

Comment: I see, so this is a log message. Can you add the message (obfuscated a little bit, but recognizable if need be) to the question?

Comment: So, I've done quite a bit of digging around the OkHttp library code, and it honestly looks like this warning comes from the inner workings of the library rather than your code. (There is also a thing where you do seem to expose the websocket in a way that it might not be torn down properly, but I'm not sure what to make of this.)

Comment: I suggest you clean this code up as much as possible, and try a "dry run" of it (with empty listener, all that), and see if the message still shows up. If it does, then you may want to [create an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues) (but first see what they already have/had, maybe yours is a duplicate).

Comment: Although, through even more digging, it appears that `WebSocket` does have a `close` method, which your app is supposed to call at some point.